# Kinetic energy for two observers

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, inertial-frames

I would greatly appreciate your views regarding this idea that came to me: Is it possible that two observers in two inertial reference frames $S$ and $S '$ where one moves with velocity $v$ with respect to the other observe the same quantity $ \Delta U_k $ for the same particle or moving object?

That is, there is some condition for it to be true that:
$ \cfrac{1}{2} m (V_2 ^ 2-V_1 ^ 2) = \cfrac{1}{2} m (V_ {2} '^ 2-V_1' ^ 2)$

My idea is that this could not be possible since if, for example, one is static and the other moves at speed $ u $ and something is observed that starts from rest (to simplify the accounts), one would obtain a kinetic energy $ E_ {k1} = \cfrac{1}{2} ma ^ 2t ^ 2 $ and another would obtain the kinetic energy $ E_ {k2} = \cfrac{1}{2}mu^2 + 2mat + \cfrac{1}{2}ma^2t^2 $ with $a$ the acceleration of the object. Which would show that these energies cannot be the same.

But then, are there conditions for the expression $\cfrac{1}{2} m (V_2 ^ 2-V_1 ^ 2) = \cfrac{1}{2}m(V_ {2} '^ 2-V_1' ^ 2)$ is fulfilled?

Comment: I would make the assumption that a photon's kinetic energy should be the same for two inertial frames since $c$ is constant.